# How to Move emails or posts from a Google group to another Google group using App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to move all the emails or posts older than 90 days to another group using Google-app-script. Is it possible to do so? Are there any other ways?

I have searched for Google Groups API, but it is not complete. The information is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Groups API is meant to manage the membership of groups, not the emails of a group.

You need to use the Gmail API to achieve what you want.  I don't think you'll find a "move" action. Consider doing the "move" in two steps: forward the old email to the other group then archive or trash the forwarded emails from the first group.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I just confirmed with Google Support that Google Groups API does not have PAI for migration or moving emails.